# Wicket: automatic field validation does not work

Tags: wicket

I have an integer field and when i enter a non integer value (let's say a symbolic one) the Feedback panel should be triggered automatically with default message, but it does not work, I have to  call it in onError method of the form by method error().

This is the textField, that i use:

```
RequiredTextField<Integer> intField =
         new RequiredTextField<>("intValue", integerValue,Integer.class);
```

this is my simple FeedBackPanel:

```
fragment.add(new FeedbackPanel("feedback"));
```

it works only when i call method error() in method onError() of the form.

Comment: Please consider applying some markdown for readability: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: The provided information is not enough to tell you where is the issue. Please provide more of your code that is related this this field and its form.

Comment: i think i have found the cause of the problem, the cause of the problem is in model which i use , i use custom model called HibernateModel in the library , which was created by our company , the name of the labrary is wicketautodao ,here is the link https://sourceforge.net/projects/wicket-autodao/

Answer (score 0):

Could you show us how you create your *Form* and the *Model* you use? As far as I understand it you will want to bind a Model to your Fields. My best guess is that your Model does not have a property "*intValue*".

You might want to (re)visit the [Wicket Wiki "More on Models"](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/More+on+models).

Comment: Nikolas i dont think so because if model does not have a property "intValue"  it would throw exception

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are setting your model. And once you add `RequiredTextField` it will not allow you empty and since you set the `Integer` type it will not allow characters to be entered.

I have tried some code snippet which is working perfectly and validating.

HomePage.html

```
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<body>
<form wicket:id="someForm">
<div wicket:id="feedback"></div>
<input type="text" wicket:id="requiredText">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

HomePage.Java

```
public class HomePage extends WebPage {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public HomePage(final PageParameters parameters) {
        super(parameters);

        Form form = new Form("someForm");
        form.add(new FeedbackPanel("feedback"));

        IModel integerValue= Model.of("");
        form.add(new RequiredTextField("requiredText",integerValue,Integer.class));
        add(form);
    }

}
```

Please let me get back to me on this incase if you need anything .